# Customize fields such as header paragraph for one page anchor links in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Currently I am working on Wordpress one page website,I have anchor links on my page which shows content on click event .I want that the content can be modified from the wp-admin for those anchor links. In short it is static right now and the code is written in index.php file.I want to make it dynamic? Can it be done through Wordpress? if yes please suggest me how can i achieve this?
this is an link to my website http://www.laughingcart.com/
I am converting it to wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible in wordpress to create dynamic page  as home page.
 know delete all your code that you have inserted in index.php and remain it as default.then access dashboard panel of the word press site then navigate to the **Pages** and create new page what ever you want modify your text place links and publish this page. then navigate to the **setting->reading**  and select the front page from drop down and save it you can now see the you pages as home page

Thanks